# Change some rows to columns, keep some rows in rows in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Every time I look at this problem, my brain shuts down.  I think it will be simple for some one else.
I have a very large dataframe that can be simplified as so:

```
day subject y variable
1   a   2.1
1   b   3.5
1   c   2.2
2   a   3.3
2   b   4.5
2   c   3.8
3   a   5.1
3   b   2.8
3   c   2.3
4   a   4.2
4   b   1.9
4   c   2.5
5   a   4.9
5   b   3.8
5   c   3.4
```

I want columns by subject, eg:

```
a     b     c
2.1   3.5   2.2
3.3   4.5   3.8
5.1   2.8   2.3
4.2   1.9   2.5
4.9   3.8   3.4
```

If some one gets me to this point, I can easily create a new column for days.  I am getting better at data manipulation, but sometimes I still get so stuck on something like this.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are the same number of a's, b's and c's? (More generally, the same number of each variable in `subject`)?

Comment: Have a look at the package `reshape2`, specifically the `dcast` function. `dcast(data, day~subject, value.var = 'y')` will probably to the trick. Many question on SO have addressed this. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+reshape+long+to+wide)

Comment: Yes, @David Robinson, there is that guarantee.  Thanks, everyone.  My dataset is too big to use code such as that in the answers, although those are good ideas.  I'm spending the day learning reshape2, as it looks like exactly what I need for my next step as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using base:

```
dat <- structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), y.variable = c(2.1, 3.5, 2.2, 3.3, 4.5, 
3.8, 5.1, 2.8, 2.3, 4.2, 1.9, 2.5, 4.9, 3.8, 3.4)), .Names = c("day", 
"subject", "y.variable"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

unstack(dat, y.variable~subject)

    a   b   c
1 2.1 3.5 2.2
2 3.3 4.5 3.8
3 5.1 2.8 2.3
4 4.2 1.9 2.5
5 4.9 3.8 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way you can do like this :

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"), y.variable = c(2.1, 3.5, 2.2, 3.3, 4.5,3.8, 5.1, 2.8, 2.3, 4.2, 1.9, 2.5, 4.9, 3.8, 3.4))
ind.a <- which(df$Subject == "a")
ind.b <- which(df$Subject == "b")
ind.c <- which(df$Subject == "c")

data.frame(a=df$y.variable[ind.a],b=df$y.variable[ind.b],c=df$y.variable[ind.c])
    a   b   c
1 2.1 3.5 2.2
2 3.3 4.5 3.8
3 5.1 2.8 2.3
4 4.2 1.9 2.5
5 4.9 3.8 3.4
```